# Database.SetInitializer not working on custom Database initializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am new in Entity Framework. I want to know about custom Database intializer as my code gives me following error: 'System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer)' has some invalid arguments.

Below is my code:

```
public class ClassifiedsContext : DbContext
{

    public ClassifiedsContext()
        : base(DataStorage.GetConnectionStringValue("AdsContext"))
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Interface IDatabaseInitializer

```
 public interface IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : global::System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{        
    void InitializeDatabase(TContext context);
}
```

class DropCreateDatabaseTables

```
 public class DropCreateDatabaseTables : IDatabaseInitializer<ClassifiedsContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ClassifiedsContext context)
    {
        bool dbExists;
        using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            dbExists = context.Database.Exists();
        }
        if (dbExists)
        {
            // remove all tables
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = \"DROP TABLE ?\"");

            // create all tables
            var dbCreationScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbCreationScript);

            Seed(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("No database instance");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Seed(ClassifiedsContext context)
    {
        /// TODO: put here your seed creation
    }
}
```

I am calling DropCreateDatabaseTables class from global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
 Database.SetInitializer<ClassifiedsContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseTables());
//I also tried this line
//Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseTables()); also gives me error
}
```

Now My code is gives me error on global.asax file

> 'System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

which is the better way of calling Database.SetInitializer from global.asax or from DBcontext

Please help me.
Thanks

EDIT 2:
This is my new code:

```
 public class DropCreateDatabaseTables : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ClassifiedsContext>
{
    public override void InitializeDatabase(ClassifiedsContext context)
    {
        bool dbExists;
        using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            dbExists = context.Database.Exists();
        }
        if (dbExists)
        {             
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = \"DROP TABLE ?\"");              
            var dbCreationScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbCreationScript);

            Seed(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("No database instance");
        }
    }

    protected override void Seed(ClassifiedsContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);           
    }
}
```